# IntelliJ IDEA with Kotlin cannot access class required by another module

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, log4j

I'm creating a new Kotlin project with multiple modules and there are issues when I try to run one of the modules from IntelliJ IDEA.

To leave the structure simple, I got `module A` and `module B`.
`module B` configures and returns `log4j2` `Logger` instance.
`module A` is calling `module B` method to get logger and uses **Logger** directly after this.

When I create a fat jar and launch methods from `module A` everything works fine and logging is working but when I try to launch `module A` method from IntelliJ IDEA I'm receiving an error from Kotlin:

```
Error:(6, 29) Kotlin: Cannot access class 'org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

Both modules are configured using Gradle and `module A` got `module B` as dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":moduleB"))
}
```

From my understanding, **IDEA** should be able to understand the requirements of `module B` and load them automatically when executing the code that uses `module B`, no?

Am I missing something?

Comment: AFAIK dependencies aren't necessarily shared across modules when it's compiled.

Comment: @Zoe, So, IDEA can't automatically detect what dependencies should be loaded into classpath before executing something?

Comment: Eh, it depends on how you compile it. A fat jar of one module included into another might work, but I think it's bare by default and loads jars from either the gradle cache, or the built directory.

Comment: @Zoe, it looks like IDEA uses the same build process that is described in project Gradle files, no? If yes, why everything works when I run build manually and execute the code but not automatically from IDE?

Comment: If you use a non-gradle run configuration, that might explain why it doesn't work. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

The problem turned out to be with `log4j` declaration in `module B`.
Initially, it was declared as:

```
implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.1")
```

So, this dependency was not exposed to `module A`.
After changing to:

```
compile("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.1")
```

No more error is produced.

Strange thing is that using `api` configuration instead of `compile` doesn't work (though, according to documentation, these are the same configurations). Looks like current IDEA Gradle plugin duoesn't support new configuration naming.

Comment: Android Studio recommands to use api and it works as of now